# Will deleting temporary files in wamp speed up my localhost server?

Tags: wamp

I have reinstalled wamp server and my project is running very fast than before. All that different is there is no tmp file in tmp folder (which was of 34GB!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache maintains website access and error logs that can grow in size very quickly. PHP also has similar logs (if enabled via configuration).

```
C:\WampDeveloper\Logs

C:\WampDeveloper\Temp
```

Once Apache log files grow in size to above several 100 MB, performance issues can arise.

Also the Temp folder holds lots of session and temporary data files that don’t get properly cleaned up, which causes it’s own issues.

To speed up Read this [WAMP is Running Very Slow](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/wamp-is-running-very-slow), This will have this points

1. Windows Hosts file
2. IPv6
3. Firewall and Anti-Virus software
4. Power Plan
5. Local Issues
6. YOUR BROWSER
7. Clear Your WAMP Log Files
8. Apache
9. MySQL
10. etc...

Comment: so is it good to clear logs and temp files from time  to  time ?

Comment: @AtulNepal happy to help :)